# Awk field separator

Tags: awk

I have a set of key value pairs in file on each line delimited by ":"

I am fetching the key value pairs using awk as mentioned below after reading each line

```
key=$(echo $LINE |  awk -F " *: *" '{print $1}')
value=$(echo $LINE |  awk -F " *: *" '{print $2}')
```

Problem is after if the value itself contains ":", it is further split and I will end up reading only value before ":" .

How can I read the entire value

Comment: Consider adding sample input and expected output to your posting. It will help to greatly reduce the guess-work. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to split on the first `:`, it will be easier to use `bash` string manipulation:

```
key=${LINE%%:*}
value=${LINE#*:}
```

`%%` lops off the longest string that matches its regex (`:*`) from the back of the string, and `#` removes the shortest string that matches at the front of the string.
e.g.

```
$ LINE="a:b:c"
$ key=${LINE%%:*}
$ value=${LINE#*:}
$ echo $key
a
$ echo $value
b:c
```

---

OK, since your shell doesn't have this, you can use `sed`:

```
key=$(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/:.*$//')
value=$(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/[^:]*://')
```

The first finds and removes everything between a colon and the end of the line, and since (most, including `sed`'s) regexes are by default greedy, that will be everything from the first colon on. The second removes everything up to and including the first colon.

Comment: this is not supported in my shell

Comment: @siri ok, addeed a way to do it in `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You're *always* going to run into problems if a field contains your delimiter. If you know that a specific field *always* contains a delimiter, you can come up with a workaround where you replace that occurrence with `sed` first:

```
echo $LINE | sed 's/:/|/3' | awk ...
```

In the above example, if you knew that the third occurrence of `:` on a line was *always* there and within a field, then you could substitute it with `|` or something similar. But that's just one hack of a solution; the real answer is to change your delimiter, if possible, or write code to parse it that can take into account something like escapes (e.g. `\:`).

Comment: or you can keep it all in awk, make the problematic field a temp variable, and `split(tmpVar, tmpArr, ":"); myVal=tmpArr[1]; myVal2=tmpArr[2];...`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old question, but using cut would make this very simple:

```
key=$(echo $LINE | cut -d: -f1)
value=$(echo $LINE | cut -d: -f2-)
```

-f2- means fields 2 until the end

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains the characters that are interpreted as delimiter symbols, then you will need to replace those characters with something else or choose a different delimiter.