# AWK FS use the 1st instance only and ignore the rest

Tags: awk, grep, separator

I have a command in which I identify the variable and then replace the variable with other values within a file(`$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/shiro.ini`). I am using a combination of printenv, grep and awk. My issue is regarding AWK and the FS variable within it. I have stated that the FS value is "="  but some of the variables have multiple "="s and I only want to count the first variable "=" as a field separator and the others as part of the string rather than other fields. Essentially what I doing right now is I collect ENV vars using printenv, grab the variables I want to focus on by using grep and then using awk and sed to iterate through those envs, format them, identify them in the file and replace them within that file.
**My command:**

```
printenv | grep "SHIRO_" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";a=""}NR > 1 { a=a" && " }{b=substr(gensub(/_/, ".", "g", $1),7);a=a"sed -ri \"s|^"b" =.+$|"b" =" $2"|g\" $ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/shiro.ini"}END{print a}' | bash
```

**Text in in shiro.ini file**

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
## search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase] = dc=COMPANY,dc=COM
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap.test.com:389
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=Users,dc=COMPANY,dc=COM
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
```

**ENV vars:**

```
SHIRO_ldapRealm_contextFactory_environment_ldap_searchBase="dc=othertypesofDNS" 
SHIRO_ldapRealm_userDnTemplate="cn={0},dc=othertypesofDNS" 
SHIRO_ldapRealm_contextFactory_url="ldap://test1.com:339 ldap://test2.com:339"
```

**Ideal output in shiro.ini file:**

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
## search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment.ldap.searchBase=dc=othertypesofDNS
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=cn={0},dc=othertypesofDNS
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url=ldap://test1.com:339 ldap://test2.com:339
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
```

**Current Output in shiro.file:**

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
## search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment.ldap.searchBase=dc
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=cn
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url=ldap://test1.com:339 ldap://test2.com:339
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
```

So, how can I make my command only use the first "=" a field separator and ignore the rest?

I've checked out the following (among others) in my quest:
[Awk field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296633/awk-field-separator)
[awk - split only by first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154996/awk-split-only-by-first-occurrence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to use `FS` for this as you don't actually WANT your records split into fields at every FS. Here's how to separate the tag/name from the value as you want (using `cat file` instead of `printenv` for demo purposes only and you don't need grep when you're using awk):

```
$ cat file |
    awk '/SHIRO_/ {
        tag=val=$0
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^=]+=/,"",val)
        print "tag="tag ORS "val="val ORS
    }'
tag=SHIRO_ldapRealm_contextFactory_environment_ldap_searchBase
val="dc=othertypesofDNS"

tag=SHIRO_ldapRealm_userDnTemplate
val="cn={0},dc=othertypesofDNS"

tag=SHIRO_ldapRealm_contextFactory_url
val="ldap://test1.com:339 ldap://test2.com:339"
```

You shouldn't be doing all that complicated stuff about creating a sed command and piping it to bash to execute either - just do whatever it is you're trying to do in the same awk command where you separate the tag from the value, e.g.:

```
$ cat file |
    awk 'sub(/^SHIRO_/,"") {
        tag=val=$0
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^=]+=/,"",val)
        gsub(/_/,".",tag)
        gsub(/"/,"",val)
        print tag"="val
    }'
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment.ldap.searchBase=dc=othertypesofDNS
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=cn={0},dc=othertypesofDNS
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url=ldap://test1.com:339 ldap://test2.com:339
```

---

EDIT: given your updated requirements:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    tag=val=$0
    sub(/ *=.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/^[^=]+= */,"",val)
    gsub(/[[_]/,".",tag)
    gsub(/]/,"",tag)
    gsub(/"/,"",val)
}
NR==FNR {
    if ( sub(/^SHIRO\./,"",tag) ) {
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }
    next
}
tag in tag2val {
    $0 = tag "=" tag2val[tag]
}
{ print }

$ cat envvars | awk -f tst.awk - shiro.ini
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
## search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment.ldap.searchBase=dc=othertypesofDNS
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url=ldap://test1.com:339 ldap://test2.com:339
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=cn={0},dc=othertypesofDNS
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
```

Comment: I am struggling to make this work such that this changes these values in a file. In your example there is no file stated whilst in my original I am substituting in an existing file. I am doing this for templating of sorts. Cat only prints and substitutes in what is being printed.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what **exactly** it is you're trying to do. Include the `printenv` output and the contents of whatever file it is you're trying to modify as the sample input/output.

Comment: I have clarified

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just wanna remove "Shiro_" from your string and . So why not do something like this:

```
 a = 'SHIRO_ldapRealm_contextFactory_environment_ldap_searchBase="dc=othertypesofDNS"'
    echo ${a#*_}
```

This for loop does that:

```
for i in $(printenv | grep "SHIRO_");
do

echo ${i#*_} | ...

done
```

Comment: Don't use that loop. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice